# How can I address Java applications launched under Expeditor?

Tags: jvm, qtp, hp-uft, expeditor

After installing QTP, Lotus Expeditor fails to start: The splash screen appears, but after it disappears, nothing happens.

So I applied one of the two workarounds described in http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lewiki.nsf/dx/Expeditor_6.2.2_Known_Issues_and_Limitations:

> Title: Work around for using QTP with Expeditor or Notes
>
> Problem abstract: Expeditor does not start if HP Quick Test
>   Professional 10.0 is installed.
>
> Details: Install QTP. Select Java Addin during custom setup for QTP.
>   Attempt to start Expeditor or Notes. The splash screen will appear but
>   the client does not launch.
>
> Resolving the Problem: There are 2 known methods that may allow
>   Expeditor or Notes to launch. Only one of these should be required.
>
> 1) Go to Registry, 2) Determine the executable name by opening
>   /framework/rcp/rcplauncher.properties on notes. Open
>   /rcp/rcplauncher.properties on Expecitor. The eclipse.name= specifies
>   the executable name. It is likely either notes2.exe or expeditor.exe.
>   2) Under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercury
>   Interactive\JavaAgent\Modules", create a DWORD value.  The name is the
>   same as the executable name.  The value is 0. This will prevent QTP
>   Java agent to be injected in the jvm.
>
> 1) Go to jvm.properties.  2) There are 2 possible locations for this
>   property file. Just change both of them to be sure you get the one
>   needed. Go to the and search for jvm.properties. 3) Using a text
>   editor add the following line: env.unset.JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

This makes Expeditor start again, but: Because Expeditor itself is a Java application, and because both workarounds keep QTP from instrumenting any JVMs, QTP also fails to recognize any Java components -- not only Expeditor's own java components, but also the Java components in all applications launched by Expeditor. These apps (of course) are those that I want to test with QTP.

This makes QTP completely incompatible with Expeditor, i.e. Java applications must be launched (and automated) outside of Expeditor. This is unacceptable for certain integration tests.

**So how can one use Expeditor with QTP installed, and use QTP´s Java addin to recognize Java objects displayed by applications launched by Expeditor?**

I do *not* need to address Expeditor's java components.